# 557. Reverse Words in a String III javascript (spacing issue)

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm solving a problem (leetcode 557) Given a string s, reverse the order of characters in each word within a sentence while still preserving whitespace and initial word order.

Example 1:

```
Input: s = "Let's take LeetCode contest"
Output: "s'teL ekat edoCteeL tsetnoc"
```

Example 2:

```
Input: s = "God Ding"
Output: "doG gniD"
```

When I write the solution below this way I get a wrong answer which is not reversed.

```js
var reverseWords = function(s) {
    let separate = s.split("");
    let res = separate.map((str) => {
        return str.split("").reverse().join("");
    });

    return res.join("")
};
```

But when I write as shown below my answer is accepted

```js
var reverseWords = function(s) {
    let separate = s.split(" ");
    let res = separate.map((str) => {
        return str.split("").reverse().join("");
    });

    return res.join(" ")
};
```

I am really confused about how the spacing in quotation marks of the second and last line of code is affecting the solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: The first approach (`s.split("");`) is going to split the string into each character, so you are essentially reversing each single character (which doesn't do anything)

Comment: Citing the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) (you did read them, didn't you): *"If `separator` is an empty string (`""`), `str` is converted to an array of each of its UTF-16 "characters""*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`s.split("")` will find every occurrence of an *emtpy* string, which is literally between *every* pair of consecutive characters. So it splits the original string into individual characters. The documentation on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) has a specific mention of this case:

> If `separator` is an empty string (`""`), `str` is converted to an array of each of its UTF-16 "characters".

`s.split(" ")` will find every occurrence of a space, which has much fewer occurrences of course, and it will split your original string into words.